# Access host on network B from machine on network A

Tags: linux, routing

My notebook has IP 1.1.1.1 and has a wired connection to another machine B that has IP 2.2.2.2. I don't have access to machine B because I locked myself out of it.

How do I have to setup routing on my notebook so I can connect to machine B?

My notebook runs Debian 9.2.

Comment: If hosts A and B are on the same [network segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segment) then you shouldn't need to do any routing. Is there a router inbetween the two hosts?

Comment: Correct, they're physically connected and there is no router in between.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you ping host B from host A? And when you say you locked yourself of out machine B, does that also mean that you don't have physical access to it?

Comment: Why would be this question unclear? It is very unclear to me.

Comment: @Jan , can you change the IPs of the notebooks?

Comment: Please edit to give more information about the pc B , the installed OS , accessible through ssh or not. how the pc A is connected? wifi?

Answer (score 7):

If they are wired without any routers in between (are in the same network segment) but aren't in the same subnet you need to setup routes on **both** devices that inform the OS that the other IP address is directly reachable via an interface. I assume your network interface is `eth0`.

On the notebook you need to execute

```
ip route add 2.2.2.2/32 dev eth0
```

On machine B you need to execute

```
ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 dev eth0
```

If both addresses are in the same subnet, the devices will automatically know that they can reach each other through interface `eth0`. Then these commands aren't neccessary.

**EDIT:** If you have no access to machine B you need to set up an address on your laptop in the same subnet as machine B.

If machine B is in subnet 2.2.2.0/24 your laptop needs an address in the range 2.2.2.1 - 2.2.2.254. You need to check how large the subnet is and add an unoccupied address in that subnet to your laptop's network interface. For example:

```
ip addr add 2.2.2.42/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: Argh. You beat me to it.

Comment: Any possibility to do this without altering machine B, where I got locked out of (that's why I'm asking)...

Comment: @Jan You might want to update your question to reflect that you don't have access to machine B. I don't think that was clear.

Comment: Added that to the question.

Comment: @Jan I extended my answer for the case that you don't have access to machine B

Comment: @Jan I think it's still not entirely clear what the problem is or what a solution would entail. If you can't log in to machine B, how is reaching it from machine A going to help? Do you have SSH keys set up or something?